# Dealing with very tall textboxes and pagination in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005.  It makes use of a page header and footer and has no subreports.  The body portion contains a few smaller elements and then a simple single column table.  The table has a single header row and a single detail row.  The header is just a label, basically.  The detail row is a single textbox with a simple Fields!FieldName.Value as its output.

The problem is that FieldName, in this case, is a highly variable length string.  It can be a sentence up to 8000 characters (usually no more than 2 pages worth).  The text can contain line/paragraph breaks (returns) but no other special formatting.  Everything is fine so long as the content fits on one page.  Once the text exceeds a single page (8.5x11), the text is very nastily cut off abruptly.  Since this is a pagination problem, it is only visible when exporting to PDF or when viewing the report in Print Layout.

It seems as though there is a maximum size the row can grow to on the first page and then it chops it off and starts it up on the second.  But this cutoff is not carefully managed in relation to the text.  It can occur right in the middle of a line, causing it to show the top halves of the letters on the first page and the bottom halves at the top of the second page.

Obviously, this is unacceptable, as it looks very unprofessional and can impair the readability of the line that was so messily split.  I also can never be sure it'll split badly, as sometimes it more or less ends the page evenly, though usually I can still see the hanging tails of certain letters on the next page (g and p for instance).

The secondary problem is that I'd really like the table row header to repeat on each page.  Setting the obvious property, "RepeatOnNewPage" has no effect.  I suspect this is because it's still trying to show the single really vertically tall row.  It seems like it's okay repeating headers and splitting pages nicely between detail rows.  But because this is basically just a big block of text, and thus just one really tall row, it doesn't split it nicely.

What can I do or use to solve this problem?  I can live without the repeating header so long as it just doesn't cut off text in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the cut-off-text problem was due to non-standard padding on the textbox in question.

For whatever reason, having padding any greater than the defaults (2pt all around) seemed to cause its pagination to go sour.  I imagine it is due to the algorithm not taking padding into consideration when deciding where to break the paragraph.  With default padding, the line always ends cleanly and nicely on each page.

As a workaround (since I liked the extra white space the padding gave to the layout), I used a rectangle to achieve the border and made the textbox inside it smaller than the rectangle by about an eighth of an inch.  This gave the box some inner padding while still apparently allowing the pagination to correctly determine when to break up lines.

Still, a lot of unnecessary headache.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, page break fine tuning is one of the biggest weak points of SSRS.

I can only suggest that you break up the long text into multiple rows before SSRS ever gets it. You'd want to parse the text to look for word breaks. The result will be odd looking breaks in the output since you won't know where the break will come on a line in the printed report. However, it'd be much more readable than cutting text in half.

If the text is comprised of reasonably sized paragraphs, you could parse it out that way instead.

You might even go so far as to measure the text using SQLCLR and the System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString method to fine tune the output but I wouldn't recommend that route for the feint of heart.

Answer (score 1):

In SSRS 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2008:

Click (not-right click) a textbox and go to the properties window (lower right side of VS) -> KeepTogether = false.

The text will cleanly cut between a line and continue on the next page.

Just thought to add here as searching for this doesn't return many results.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what JC has suggested in the past where I've broken down the text into paragraphs and each paragraph would in effect be its own row. Works pretty well given the limitations of SSRS.

One thing to be careful about is that you would need to make sure that your paragraphs sort properly. In most cases it would display them in the correct order, but adding in a column with sortID to give some sorting hints to the table would probably be a good idea.